# 自作のwordpress pluginのライセンス表示について

Tags: wordpress, ライセンス

今回、Apache License 2.0で公開されているSDKを改変して、wordpressのpluginを作成したので公開しようとしています。
そこで質問です。

Apache License 2.0

> 4. 再頒布
>
> あなたは、ソース形式であれオブジェクト形式であれ、変更の有無に関わらず、以下の条件をすべて満たす限りにおいて、成果物またはその派生成果物のコピーを複製したり頒布したりすることができます。
>   ...省略

とありますが、具体的にどうすればいいのかわかりません。

今回私が作成した3ファイルのうち、2つは元々公開されていたものそのままコピーで、1ファイルだけコピーせず完全に新規に作った、という状況です。

この場合、GitHubにあげるにあたり、作成時にLISENCE => Apache License 2.0を選択すると
できるLISENCEファイルの

```
Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]
```

を元の作成者の情報を入力。

wordpress plugin 側のコードの先頭に

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: xxxxxxxx
 * Plugin URI:  xxxxxx (github url)
 * Description: xxxxxxx
 * Version:     0.1
 * Author:      xxxxxx
 * Author URI:  xxxxxx
 * License:     Apache License 2.0
 * Text Domain: xxxxx
 * Domain Path: xxxxxx
 */
```

こちらで足りますか？
まだ他に記載すべき事項はありますか？

Answer (score 0):

<sub>WordPress プラグインは原則 GPLv2またはそれ以降をプラグインのライセンスとする <del>必要があります</del> ことが推奨されています。([ex参照](https://www.slideshare.net/YutakaKachi/wordpress-114644479))

Apache License 2.0はGPLv3と互換性があるので、GPLv3のプラグインコードに同梱してそのSDKを再頒布することは問題ないでしょう。</sub>

<sub>(とはいえ、[ライセンスのガイドライン](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#1-plugins-must-be-compatible-with-the-gnu-general-public-license)にもあるようにApache Licenseをプラグインに採用することは問題ないはずですね……)</sub>

---

(派生物ではありますが、)プラグインの主体自体はSDKではなく自身で作成された部分となるはずなのでLICENSEファイルやヘッダーには**プラグインの**ライセンスを記載するべきでしょう。

もし、SDKのコード内にコメントなどでもとのライセンスが明記されている場合、特段それ以上はしなくても構わないかもしれませんが、その利用SDKにほかのライセンスを示すファイルが同梱されている場合それを含めるべきかもしれません。(その場合、サブディレクトリにSDKを配置し同階層にそれらのファイルを配置するなどの対応をとっておくとわかりやすいでしょう。)

そうでない場合、SDK部のライセンスがなんらかの形で明記(上のようにライセンスファイルの同梱やコメントへの記載の追加など)によりプラグイン利用者がそのライセンス情報にアクセスできれば問題ないはずです。

<sub>途中まで書いてすこし書いたことが怪しい気がしてきました……</sub>